# Fastest way to read a large binary file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to read a simple but large (500MB) binary file in Python 3.6.  The file was created by a C program, and it contains 64-bit double precision data.  I tried using struct.unpack but that's very slow for a large file.

Here is my simple file read:

```
def ReadBinary():

    fileName = 'C:\\File_Data\\LargeDataFile.bin'

    with open(fileName, mode='rb') as file:
        fileContent = file.read()
```

Now I have fileContent.  What is the fastest way to decode it into 64-bit double-precision floating point, or read it without the need to do a format conversion?

I want to avoid, if possible, reading the file in chunks.  I would like to read it decoded, all at once, like C does.

Comment: Maybe you can use [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/mmap.html)? See the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30022899/10035985

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`array.array('d')`'s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) `fromfile` method:

```
def ReadBinary():
    fileName = r'C:\File_Data\LargeDataFile.bin'

    fileContent = array.array('d')
    with open(fileName, mode='rb') as file:
        fileContent.fromfile(file)
    return fileContent
```

That's a C-level read as raw machine values. `mmap.mmap` could also work by creating a `memoryview` of the `mmap` object and casting it.

Comment: I'll try that out now.

Comment: I get this message:  'array.array' has no attribute 'array'

Comment: That was because I had "from array import array" in my imports; when I changed to "import array" the problem was solved.

Comment: @RTC222: Yeah, I'm not a fan of the "module and only class in it share the same name" thing. In modern Python, they probably would have named the class `Array` (matching PEP8 for non-built-ins, like `collections.OrderedDict`), but we're stuck with legacy names forever, whee!

Comment: I don't like that either because it's confusing. I also prefer to import the whole module, not just a class (e.g. from xxx import yyy).